# Channel Images and IIS paths

Tags: channel-images, windows, iis

I'm trying to use channel images on a Windows server, but channel images uses a '/' for the paths on the actions instead of letting me use ' \'. Anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried letting channel images use / instead of \ Windows servers usually don't mind which way the slash goes.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was trying to outsmart the server by adding extra forward slashes. Removed those and it worked perfectly.